# eBay is demanding that I register for them to "manage my payments"

Tags: ebay, ecommerce

I very rarely sell anything on eBay.

Over the past few months, I've gotten emails from them saying I must register for them (or them + payoneer) to manage my payments.

Now they've said I won't be able to sell anything, ever, if I don't register for that.

The thing is, I thought they were already "managing" my payments via paypal; they even withheld a payment made to me on an item I sold.

My questions:

- Why is this happening?
- Can I avoid this somehow?
- If I can't - what are the gotchas of this scheme? I mean, what do they want to "manage" now that they couldn't earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this is something you can avoid, as eBay has changed their payment services for sellers from PayPal to another (I believe their own) service. Unless they've made another recent policy change, you have to now connect a bank account if you are a seller to receive payments. Buyers (I believe) can still use PayPal.

The only "scheme" I can think of is that they've likely changed this system for financial reasons of their own, ex. if PayPal was charging eBay fees for both sides of the transaction on buyer and seller money transfers.